# Has Google News removed the search by year option?

Tags: google-news

I can't find the option now in Google News to search by year. Any idea where it is?

It used to be on the far left.

Now when I google for news search by year I get

[Google News Archive Search](http://news.google.com/archivesearch)

and I get this ugly screen up. But notice the part for M/d/yy is disabled. I can't edit it / put a date or rate range in.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screen shot you provide, if you change the menu from "in archive" to "specified dates" you'll be able to edit the date fields.

Answer (score 1):

After you perform a search, you should get a button at the top of the search results labelled "Search tools".

If you click that, a menu opens with three filters:

- All news - which allows toggling between "all news" and "blogs"
- Any time - which allows you to choose among several different pre-sent time periods or a custom range
- Sorted by relevance - which you can toggle with "sorted by date"

The custom date range is obviously what you want.